# Unable to get desired result while using $lookup in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is the query I have written here I am joining the recipes table and users table. The recipe table has a 'posted by the field which includes the `_id` of the user, who posted that recipe.

```
const Recipe = mongoose.model("Recipe");
Recipe.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            title: 1,
            steps: 1,
            serves: 1,
            cuisine_type: 1,
            time: 1,
            Ingredients: 1,
            foodtype: 1,
            postedby: 1,
            photo: 1,
            likes: {
                $size: '$likes'
            },
        }
    },
    {
        $match: { // Filter documents that don't have likes >= 0
            likes: {
                $gte: 0
            }
        }
    }
]).lookup({ from: 'users', localField: 'postedby', foreignField: '_id', as: 'usersnamee' })
    .then(doc => {
        if (!doc) {
            return res.status(422).json({ error: "Cannot find recipes" })
        }
        console.log(doc)


    })
})
```

This is the output that I got: [take a look at the usersnamee field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMIgF.png)

Comment: the response is just wrapped in console view, three is result data, stringify response and console it.

Comment: Thankyou @turivishal , I just added console.log(JSON.stringify(doc)) and I got desired response. It now feels like a silly question.